# Issue in iterating values using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have stuck up with an issue of retrieving multiple values from edit text using jquery. I have two dynamic input text box , while retrieving , i can able to get one column of text. How to get both input text box values

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
        var values = "";
        var values1 = "";
        $("input[name=name]").each(function () {
            values += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });
        alert(values);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return '<input name = "name" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;<input name = "designation" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
}
</script>
```

> ```
> **Output:**
> ```
>
> > name:Ram
> >         name:Tom

```
**Expected Output:**
name:Ram , deisgnation:SE
name:Tom, Designation:PM
```

Comment: According to your code the output is correct. You need to get the values of texbox with name attribute equal to designation the same way you are doing it for others.

Comment: can you show in fiddle?

Comment: Don't show in fiddle, show it here with stack snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You're only getting values of the `name` inputs, not the `designation` inputs.

```
$("input[name=name]").each(function() {
    values += "Name:" + $(this).val();
    values += ", designation:" + $(this).next().val() + "\n";
});
```